# APNS device token is getting generated incorrect

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I have integrated apple push notification and facing a strange problem in my application. when I directly install the application via Xcode through usb connection then the device token is being generate stored in database correctly and push notification is working fine. but when I create IPA and install the app via created ipa in the same device then the device token is getting generated wrong and push notification is not working. Below is my code:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:      [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
                             (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings
        *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
#endif


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData
    *)deviceToken {
      const unsigned *tokenData = deviceToken.bytes;
                    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x%08x", ntohl(tokenData[0]),ntohl(tokenData[1]),ntohl(tokenData[2]),ntohl(tokenData[3]),ntohl(tokenData[4]),ntohl(tokenData[5]),ntohl(tokenData[6]),ntohl(tokenData[7])];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:deviceTokenString forKey:@"devicetoken"];
      NSLog(@"Device Token = %@", deviceTokenString);
}

//Failed to Register for Remote Notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error in registration. Error: %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The device Token depends on the certificate you signed your application with. If you install directly it is the dev-certificate, while when signing for AdHoc it is a distribution certificate. For push you need a corresponding distribution or development certificate packed on your server.

Comment: Usually that is the case. But it is also possible to set to install directly as adhoc release with adhoc certificate. (I am myself debuging ad-hoc push notification in this way.. Faster than creating an ad-hoc release, uploading to apple, etc..  Problem is that it does not allow to debug if installed as ad-hoc directly. (app closes after few seconds. But then again, I can open Devices and see the console output anyway).